# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 using Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I know this question has been asked previously, but I cannot find out what is the exact problem with my code.

```
function viewcalldetails(obj) {
                alert("clicked");
                var id = $(obj).attr("id");
                $(".style-table-tab input[type='text']").val('');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('.preloader-circle').show();// or fade, css display however you'd like.
                }, 1000);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: pageUrl+"/LoadCallDetails",
                    data: '{LeadID: "' + id + '"}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: OnValuecall,
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                    }
                });
            }


            function OnValuecall(response) {
                $(".preloader-circle").hide();
                $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbrfullname").text(response.d.FirstName);
                $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbrphonenumber").text(response.d.MobileNo);
                $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbraddress").text(response.d.Address1);
                $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbrorganization").text(response.d.OrganizationName);
                $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblremail").text(response.d.PrimaryEmail);

            }
```

Web Method:

```
public static UserAjax3 LoadCallDetails(string LeadID)
    {
        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        UserAjax3 oUserAjax = new UserAjax3();

        //BD_CommonEmail[] ocall = BD_CommonEmail.GetEmailAll(Convert.ToInt32(LeadID)).ToArray();
        BD_Leads[] ocall = BD_Leads.getCallDetails(Convert.ToInt32(LeadID)).ToArray();
        if (ocall.Length == 1)
        {
            //   oUserAjax.LeadID = oLeads.LeadID.ToString();
            oUserAjax.LeadID = ocall[0].LeadID.ToString();
            oUserAjax.FirstName = ocall[0].FirstName;
            oUserAjax.MobileNo = ocall[0].MobileNo;
            oUserAjax.OrganizationName = ocall[0].OrganizationName;
            oUserAjax.Address1 = ocall[0].Address1;
            oUserAjax.PrimaryEmail = ocall[0].PrimaryEmail;
        }
        return oUserAjax;
```

Comment: why don't you set a break point check if `LoadCallDetails` is be called. if not check your post url.

Comment: I have checked using break point.But no call made to LoadcallDetails @CodeFarmer

Answer (score 3):

There are many things in question:

1. Where does "pageUrl" comes from?
2. You're awaiting a JSON result, but your method seems to return a normal object. Where do you convert to JSON?
3. Did you try running with a debugger in single-step mode trhough your web method?
4. Why is your web method static?

Comment: Let me guess - it was wrong pageUrl?! Because if your breakpoint never gets hit, then probably your calling address is wrong.